# Iterate over elements of strings at the same time

Tags: python

I have a dictionary containing sentences that is keyed by the `book` and the `page` from which it came from:

```
# lists to build dictionary - for reproducibility  
pages     = [12, 41, 50, 111, 1021, 121]
bookCodes = ['M', 'P', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'M']

sentences = ['THISISASENTANCE',
             'ANDHEREISONEMOREEXAMP',
             'ALLFROMDIFFERENTBOOKS',
             'ANDFROMDIFFERENTPAGES',
             'MOSLTYTHESAMELENGTHSS',
             'BUTSOMEWILLBABITSHORT'
             ]

# Make dictionary 
coordinates = defaultdict(dict)
for i in range(len(pages)):
    book = bookCodes[i]
    page = pages[i]
    sentence = sentences[i]
    coordinates[book][page] = sentence 

print coordinates
```

---

```
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {'A': {50: 'ALLFROMDIFFERENTBOOKS', 1021: 'MOSLTYTHESAMELENGTHSS'}, 'P': {41: 'ANDHEREISONEMOREEXAMP'}, 'C': {111: 'ANDFROMDIFFERENTPAGES'}, 'M': {121: 'BUTSOMEWILLBABITSHORT', 12: 'THISISASENTANCE'}})
```

---

I also have a pool of vowels stored as a dictionary, so that each vowel starts with a count of 10:

`vowels = dict.fromkeys(['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'], 10)`

I want to iterate over the same element of each sentence (`sentence[0][0]. sentence[n][0], ...`) and each time I see a vowel (`A`, `E`, `I`, `O`, or `U`) reduce the count of this vowel from the `vowels` dictionary.

Once a pool of vowels hits `0` I return the `letter`, `position` in the sentence, and `sentence` and break the loop.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import random

def wordStopper(sentences):
    random.shuffle(sentences)
    vowels = dict.fromkeys(['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'], 10)
    for i in range(len(sentences[1])):
        for s in sentences:
            try:
                l = s[i:i + 1]
            except IndexError:
                continue

            if l in vowels:
                vowels[l] -= 1
                print("Pos: %s, Letter: %s, Sentence: %s" % (i, l, s))
            print("As = %s, Es = %s, Is = %s, Os = %s, Us = %s" %(vowels['A'], vowels['E'], vowels['I'], vowels['O'],  vowels['U']))
            if vowels[l] == 0:
                return(l, i, s)

letter, location, sentence = wordStopper(sentences)
print("Vowel %s exhausted here %s in sentence: %s" % (letter, location, sentence))
```

It's important that the `sentences` list is shuffled (and that I iterate over element `0` in all sentences, and then element `1`), so that I don't bias towards earlier entries in the `sentences` list.

This works as I expect, but I now want to retrieve the `book` and `page` number from which the `sentence` was pulled which are stored in `coordinates`.

I can crudely achieve this by iterating over `coordinates` and finding the `sentence` that is returned from `wordStopper`:

```
print coordinates

for book in coordinates.keys():
    for page, s in coordinates[book].iteritems():
        if s == sentence:
            print("Book:%s, page: %s, position: %s, vowel: %s, sentence: %s" % (book, page, location, letter, sentence))
```

**However** This strikes me as a fairly poor way of achieving this.

Normally, I might iterate over the keys of `coordinates` before the sentences, but I can't see a way to do this so that it doesn't bias the results towards the first keys that are iterated over.

Any suggestions are very welcome
**Note**: this is toy example, so I'm not looking to use any corpus parsing tools

Comment: i don't know if you still have access to `sentences`, `pages`, and `bookCodes`, but you could use `index = sentences.index(sentence)` and work from there

Comment: you have parallel lists and therefore, the index of `sentence` in `sentences` will be the correct index in `pages` and `bookCodes`. caveat: `index()` will only provide the index of the first match in your list.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you need is a better data structure, that would let you to retrieve the book/page from the sentence. There are many possible designs. This is what I would do:

First, Create a data structure that holds a sentence, along with its book/page:

```
class SentenceWithMeta(object):
    def __init__(self, sentence):
        self.sentence = sentence
        self.book = None
        self.page = None
```

Then, hold all your sentences. For example:

```
sentences_with_meta = [SentenceWithMeta(sentence) for sentence in sentences]
```

At this point, initialize sentences_with_meta fields book and page fields:

```
# Make dictionary
sentences_with_meta = [SentenceWithMeta(sentence) for sentence in sentences]
for i in range(len(pages)):
    book = bookCodes[i]
    page = pages[i]
    sentence_with_meta = sentences_with_meta[i]
    sentence_with_meta.book = book
    sentence_with_meta.page = page
```

Finally, in the wordStopper method, work with sentences_with_meta array, the following way:

```
def wordStopper(sentences):
    random.shuffle(sentences_with_meta)
    vowels = dict.fromkeys(['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'], 10)
    for i in range(len(sentences[1])):
        for swm in sentences_with_meta:
            try:
                l = swm.sentence[i:i + 1]
    ...
    # the rest of the code is the same. You return swm, which has the book
    # and page already in the structure.
```

Side node: To get letter i from a string, you don't need to use slice. Just use the index reference:

```
l = swm.sentence[i]
```

There are many many other designs that would work as well.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you've done here. Where is the book/page information stored in your object (as you set it `None`)?

Comment: fugu, during construction I only put None. In my sample code, I didn't write the functionality you titled as "#Make dictionary". You should do whatever you are doing today, but replace this line: coordinates[book][page] = sentence with sentence.book = book, sentence.page = page