# Build class to iterate over returned structure

Tags: python, class

I am trying to build a data structure that contains three pieces of information: a `book` name, a `page` number and a `sentence`.

I am currently making a dictionary with two keys `coordinates[book][page] = sentence`. However, I want to iterate over my sentences without having to iterate through `book` and `page` keys (**as I need the order in which they're accessed to be random**).

For the purposes of reproducibility here's the data structure I am creating:

```
pages     = [12, 41, 50, 111, 1021, 121]
bookCodes = ['M', 'P', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'M']


sampledSentances = ['THISISASENTANCE',
                    'ANDHEREISONEMOREEXAMP',
                    'ALLFROMDIFFERENTBOOKS',
                    'ANDFROMDIFFERENTPAGES',
                    'MOSLTYTHESAMELENGTHSS',
                    'BUTSOMEWILLBABITSHORT'
                    ]

from collections import defaultdict
coordinates = defaultdict(dict)

for b, p, s in zip(bookCodes, pages, sampledSentances):
    coordinates[b][p] = s

print coordinates
```

What I'm actually trying to do, is iterate over `sampledSentances` with the `book` and `page` information associated.

From reading around, (and from a [question I asked yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51382157/iterate-over-elements-of-strings-at-the-same-time)) it sounds like I should be building an iterable class object.

Here's what I've tried, but I'm not sure how I can use this to iterate over `sampledSentances`, or even whether this is the right approach at all:

```
# A class to build the object
class Sentence(object):
    def __init__(self, b, p, s):
        self.book     = b
        self.page     = p
        self.sentence = s

    def getInfo(self):
        return self.book, self.page, self.sentence

# Make a list, and append the book, page and sentence generated from the `Sentence` class
sentenceInfo = []
for b, p, s in zip(bookCodes, pages, sampledSentances):
    sentenceInfo.append(Sentence(b, p, s).getInfo())

print(sentenceInfo)
```

I'm new to Classes in Python, and any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use [generator function](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) for this task

```
def iterSentances(bookCodes, pages, sampledSentances):
    zz = list(zip(bookCodes, pages, sampledSentances))
    random.shuffle(zz)
    for ss in zz:
        yield ss

for b,p,s in iterSentances(bookCodes, pages, sampledSentances):
    print(b,p,s)
```

Comment: Thanks. I need to randomly order `sampledSentances`. I currently use `random.shuffle(sampledSentances)` to shuffled the sentences before I iterate over them. How can I implement this approach with shuffled sentences (but keep the correct associations with `book` and `page`)?

Comment: Updated. You can shuffle the tuples.